# MVC checkbox comeing back null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a checkbox, but the form is being submitted the value ticked are not being submited...

Html:

```
@foreach (var radiobutton in Model.InterestedIn)
           {
             <span >  @Html.CheckBox("selected", radiobutton)
               <label>@radiobutton</label></span>
               <br />
           }
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Would you be interested in receiving *")]
        public IList<string> InterestedIn { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
IList<string> lists = new List<string>();
            lists.Insert(0, "Latest News");
            lists.Insert(1, "Special Offers");
            lists.Insert(1, "New Products");
            model.InterestedIn = lists;
```

PostMethod:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Competition model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
```

Comment: What does the post method in the controller look like? What's its signature? How are you attempting to access the checkbox values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't that your code will compile at all. The `CheckBox` helper expects a boolean as second argument whereas you are passing it a string.

Try like this:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var value in Model.InterestedIn)
    {
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="interestedin" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(value)" />
            <label>@value</label>
        </span>
        <br />
    } 
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

This assumes that you have the following view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Would you be interested in receiving *")]
    public IList<string> InterestedIn { get; set; }
}
```

and the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<string> lists = new List<string>();
        lists.Insert(0, "Latest News");
        lists.Insert(1, "Special Offers");
        lists.Insert(1, "New Products");
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.InterestedIn = lists;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If you want to use the `CheckBox` or even better the `CheckBoxFor` helper you will have to adapt your view model so that it no longer has an `IList<string>` property but an `IList<CheckBoxItemViewModel>` property where `CheckBoxItemViewModel` is another view model that will contain the label and a boolean property indicating whether this value has been selected or not.

Comment: any help with the same issue happening to my drop down list?